# how to check if a variable is equal to a word

Tags: c, string

I have this code. I want that when the user writes yes the program will print OK.
However, the program writes

> "yes is undeclared".

How can I make the program treat to `'yes'` as a word and not as a variable?

```
char a = ' ';
scanf("%c",&a);
if(a == yes)
{
    printf("OK");
}
```

Comment: You need to read a good C book, you don't seem to have grasped the basic concepts yet.

Comment: char is for one letter. if you wanna input a string you will have to use char[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, `'yes'` is *not* a *word* (*sting, if you mean that*), `"yes"` is.

---

That said, you're way out of league for the idea. One *possible* implementation can look like

1. First, you need to define an array for the input, like `char a[12] = "no"`; because you need to store more than one *character* as per your need. (*the size used here is just indicative*).
2. Scan the user input using `scanf()`, like `scanf("%11s", a)`;
3. Use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) from `string.h`, for comparison, like `if (!strcmp(a, "yes"))`.

Another possible implementation could make use of an `enum` of `"YES"` and `"no"`, take the user choice as integer and make use of the good old `==` comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems in your code.

First of all, you declare `a` as a `char` (character) which means you can't compare it to "yes" because that's a string, or `char` array because this is C.

It's composed of 4 characters (3 for the text, 1 for the `\0`; in C "strings" are null-terminated so there has to be an ending character).

Declare your variable and read it like this:

```
#include <string.h> //you need this for string comparison

char a[10]; //arbitrary size, just make sure it's big enough for the input
scanf("%s", a);
//OR
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin); //use fgets if you need to read more than one word, scanf stops reading at whitespace
//don't use == to compare strings
if (!strcmp(a, "yes")){ //use quotes to delimit "words"
    printf("OK\n");
}
```

Comment: "*... since this is C, a char array*" which makes `"yes"` a `char` array with *4* elements, due to the `0`-terminator uses by C-"strings".

Comment: @alk Does that apply to string literals though?

Comment: Yes, it definitely does.

Comment: So when you write string literals like `"foo"` the null character is implied?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes ... :-)

Comment: And if it were not, how would `strlen("yes")` work? Or `const char * p = "yes"; const char * q; <some logic assigning q, some  times to be p> ... strlen(q);`

Comment: @alk reminds me of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIVy5XdQhOM) .. :P